# Missing end time Google Calendar when insert event

Tags: php, http, post, google-calendar-api

I trying to insert an event in the Google Calendar. The authentication and to fetch events works without any problems. Unfortunately I got the following error message:

```
{
  error: {
     errors: [
        {
          domain: "global",
          reason: "required",
          message: "Missing end time."
        }
     ],
     code: 400,
     message: "Missing end time."
   }
}
```

I request the site with cURL in PHP. To count the Content-Length for the request I using the function `countArrayChars()`. The following is my code:

```
$start = date("c", strtotime($start));
$end = date("c", strtotime($end));

$data_array = array(
  "end"=>array("dateTime"=>$end),
  "start"=>array("dateTime"=>$start),
  "summary"=>$name
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-length: ".countArrayChars($data_array),"Content-type: application/json","Authorization: Bearer $access_token\r\n"),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_array
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $resp;

function countArrayChars(array $array){
    $charNumber = 0;
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($val, $key) use (&$charNumber)
    {
        $charNumber += strlen($val) + strlen($key);
    });
    return $charNumber;
}
```

What I also tried is to set the data as a http_build_query, as well as a json_encode result. Unfortunately this also didn't work.

Thanks for every response.

**UPDATE:**

```
$data_array = array(
  "end"=>array("dateTime"=>$end,"timeZone"=>"Europe/Zurich"),
  "start"=>array("dateTime"=>$start,"timeZone"=>"Europe/Zurich"),
  "summary"=>$name
);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

This is the output of `$end`

```
string(25) "2017-03-10T00:00:00+01:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you, but this is the code I use to add events to google calendar through the API:

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => $summary,
  'location' => $location,
  'description' => $description,
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => $startdatetime,
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => $enddatetime,
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
  ),
));
```

You usually need to add a timezone, like I have, which could be your problem. I would suggest trying that out first.

**Update:**

I can't find anything else that could be wrong with your code, it's probably something having to do with how Google accepts data. All I can offer you now is exactly how I do mine, which I know works:

First, follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts) to setup service account, if not done already. Make sure to create a .p12 file, instead of JSON.

You can download the PHP Google Calendar File [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) as well, without needing to use composer.

Next, work with the code below to suit your needs, but this should work for you. (The dateTime was properly formatted before it was sent in POST, so you may need to change that)

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once __DIR__ . '/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

$summary = $_POST["summary"];
$location = $_POST["location"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$startdatetime = $_POST["startdatetime"];
$enddatetime = $_POST["enddatetime"];




$client_email = "clientemail"; //client email setup when you create the authorization in Google Developer Console.
$private_key = file_get_contents("privatekey.p12"); //location on your server where the .p12 file you created is stored
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$user_to_impersonate = "primary"; //This can also be an email address associated with the current gmail login if you don't want to use the default one
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key,
    'notasecret',                                 // Default P12 password
    'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer', // Default grant type
    $user_to_impersonate
); //Keep everything in this array the same
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => $summary,
  'location' => $location,
  'description' => $description,
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => $startdatetime,
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => $enddatetime,
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
  ),
));
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarId = $useremail;
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
echo json_encode($event);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately this uses the Google API Client Library for PHP. I want to try using it via cURL. I added the timeZone attributes, but it also didn't work.

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you added the timezone? It has to be added to the same array that the end time is in or it won't work.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you declare your original `$end` variable? All I see is `$end = date("c", strtotime($end));` but there isn't an original `$end` variable to do `strtotime($end)`. Was it from a POST or GET request?

Comment: Yes, it will get it via a GET request.

Comment: Ok, good. Have you tried printing the new $end variable to the screen to make sure that the format is correct? Try `$end = date("c", strtotime($end)); echo $end;`

Comment: I can't find anything else that could be causing any issues, so it may just be a weird thing that Google has with how it requires data to be sent, so I updated my answer to show you exactly how mine works, which is fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `$start` is less than `$end`.

Answer (score 0):

the error of google is not correct.
you have to check al inputfield for strange symbols. I had Straße in locationfield...that gave the missing endtime error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem may be on special characters in the variable, must try to encode UTF-8.

please try this

```
'summary' => utf8_encode($summary),
'description' => utf8_encode($descripcion),
'location' => utf8_encode($location),
```

regards,
Luis